# Can I use the function as a reference directly into the other function?

Tags: c++

As the code below, this example defines a function "Func" as an input to the function for_each. The problem is that can I directly do this? Do I need to firstly define a function pointer like `template<typename T> void (*Func)(const T& x);` Or, this is just because Func is a random function? Also, in this example, why we need const and reference&?

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
void for_each(T* begin, T* end, const Func& f)
{
    while (begin != end) f(*begin++);
}

template <typename T>
void print(const T& x)
{
    std::cout << x << " ";
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for_each(arr, arr + 5, print<int>);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "directly do this"? You can have function pointers as function arguments, but that then disallows function like objects (such as created by lambda expressions). Also the meaning of `const` references is the same here as in any other function

Comment: yes, you can!  x

Comment: It is not very clear what your first question is about. Are you asking whether the code is legal? Yes it is. You don't actually need `const` and `&` here.

Comment: I mean directly give a function as input to a function. I learn that I should define a function pointer and input this function pointer rather than give the function name as the input.

Comment: *"I learn that I should define a function pointer and input this function pointer rather than give the function name as the input."* -- I question the reliability of the source of this information.

Comment: My first question is, in most case, if I want to give a function as input, I need to first define a function pointer, but in this example, a template is used as a function and directly used as a input to another function. Why can it do that?

Comment: @Maccchiatooo the code you have shown [works fine as-is](https://ideone.com/8SAcGq). You don't need to define a function pointer type since the `Func` parameter is templated. The compiler will deduce the pointer type for you. In fact, the `begin` and `end` parameters shouldn't be defined as pointers, let the compiler reduce their types, too. `template <typename T, typename Func> void for_each(T begin, T end, const Func& f)` Pointers are valid iterators, but iterators are not required to be pointers. BTW, look at [`std::for_each()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

Comment: "I need to first define a function pointer" Not really. First, you can pass functions by reference jolly well, no pointers need be involved (this is what happens in this example). Second, when you do *not* pass functions by reference, you don't need to *define* a function pointer either, because one is created for you automatically (you can remove the `&` and see that the code is still working).

Comment: So, can I write a function ` int Funct( int a, int b, fun1){return fun1(a,b);}  int fun1(int a, int b) {return a*b;}`?

Comment: Have you tried it? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: No you cannot write that. The identifier `fun1` inside `int Funct(...)` is meaningless. You need a parameter declaration there. `fun1` is not a parameter declaration. A parameter declaration for a function pointer looks like `int (*func)(int, int)`. You can also write `int func(int, int)` but the meaning is actually exactly the same.